# Qt C++ delete float** elements in a QList<float**>

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, delete-operator

I have a `QList<float**>`. I first iterate on elements to work with them:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < nb ; i++ )
{
    float** data1 = data_list.at( i ) ;
    float** data2 = data_list.at( i + 1 ) ;
    // do things with data1 and data2

}
```

What happens if I `delete[]` in a C-stylish manner `data1` and `data2` inside this loop? Are elements at position `i` and `i+1` in `data_list` destroyed as well (so that `i` cannot access them anymore) ?

Comment: The elements pointed to are deleted, but the (now dangling) pointers are still there.

Comment: And make sure that `nb` is at least 1 smaller than `data_list.size()` ....

Comment: You may also be interested in [qDeleteAll()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll) if you wanted to move away from the C-style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a list of `float**`. The `float*` they are pointing to are not in the list.
which means if you use `delete[]`, the memory is released, but  `data_list` itself doesnt change. After this point they will be invalid pointers.